# ez publish competitors as internally good cms / framework

Tags: content-management-system, ezpublish

i need to put a corporate site under a cms, which i haven't finally chosen yet, and have some tight requirements for it:

1. it should be very well organized at a code level, as i'm a developer and i need to add some very custom functionality to the site;
2. ability to create custom content types (a la drupal's cck does);
3. very good i18n abilities as the site will be multilingual to and fro;
4. caching / performance control solutions as the site experiences tens of thousands unique hosts a day;
5. publishing features like pre-moderation, authoring and versioning;
6. sending custom emails;
7. creating custom web forms with input data validation;
8. content access levels;
9. i would like to have my static content (images / css / pdf's etc) on a separate domain (possibly hosted on amazon cloud) processed by caching proxy server like nginx -- not a tight requirement, but still;

i evaluated these requirements and came up with ez publish as a solution. i'm not very experienced in cms world; i've worked with drupal and wordpress, but, being good cms'es, none of these meet my requirements (drupal isn't good at a code level and wordpress is a blog solution). also i don't want to mess with joomla or complexity of typo3. so, my question is -- does ez publish have a competitor in this field, regardless of the implemention language?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already went through a clear requirement analysis and already figured that eZ Publish meets them all, there is no other need for me than pointing you to the very welcoming eZ Publish Community, in case you would like to have more in-depth, real-life feedback on every of your points above, by eZ Community members.

You can find them there : http://share.ez.no

A recent code-level comparison between eZ Publish & Drupal confirms your intuition : http://share.ez.no/blogs/marko-zmak/ezpublish-vs.-drupal

I must confess i liked reading your :

> .. and wordpress is a blog solution

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to agree with Nicolas.  I worked for about 4 years doing custom CMS integration for companies of all different sizes and requirements and to this day I haven't found an open source CMS that has the abilities of eZ Publish.

During that time I also did a lot of implementations of "Conversational Marketing" (blogs with marketing purposes) and they were of course all in WordPress.  WordPress can be extended to do a lot of different things, but you're very correct in your pigeonholing of it as a blog solution.  Any customization of it requires you to extrapolate your problem as if it was a blogging issue.

With eZ Publish, the community involvement is very expansive and the core of the CMS is built to be customized in any way you would like.

Best of luck, and I would agree with your choice and Nicolas's vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

eZ Publish is definitely the right answer here as it meets to all your requirements by its built-in features or by its extensions.
Yes, eZ Publish learning curve can be tough, but it worths the effort !

Answer (score 1):

eZ Publish will definitely deliver all of those functional requirements almost 100% out-of-the-box. Also, check out the eZ Components / Zeta Components library used by that CMS.  Feature-wise TYPO3 is also strong but the code isn't so clean ( IMHO ).
The only other system I know of that can come close is Plone CMS ( Python based ).